# Error Message is displayed when I am using log.v() statement in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a class which uses an ArrayList and I'm using log.v() function to display ArrayList elements in the log. As per the instructions in the course. I am encountering an error when I am using the log statement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Log` starts with capital L. Also make sure you have all necessary imports.

Answer (score 1):

From the image i see that should be "Log" with the L in uppercase, also make sure that you are doing 
`import android.util.Log;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! It indeed helped. Anyways I made a silly mistake. Thank you